# Why can't I fire custom events?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to fire custom events using jquery but for some reason I can't seem to fire and/or capture them.

I'm using a jstree plugin to create a file system with folders:

```
$('.filetree.global, .filetree.workspace').bind('select_node.jstree', function (event, data) {
    alert('test ');
    $(document).trigger( 'filePick').trigger( 'folderPick' );
}).jstree({
    /*stuff*/
});
```

Further down the code I'm binding the filePick and folderPick events to elements with a specific class and tell them to alert a test message whenever they catch the event:

```
$('.folder-action').bind( 'folderPick', function(e, data) {
    alert('test 2');
} );
```

Unfortunately the alert never gets triggered and I don't know why. The jquery documentation seems pretty clear to me and I followed a different tutorial which also seems to indicate that my code should work but it just isn't! ARGH!

'test 1' gets alerted but not 'test 2'. Also, I installed Eventbug (Firebug extension) and I can see that my bindings to filePick are registered which leads me to believe that filePick and folderPick are just never fired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery events bubble up, but not down. This means that when you trigger the event on the *document*, it will not trigger down to elements inside the document. You can either trigger the event on that element, or trigger the event globally.

To trigger on that element, do this:

```
$('.folder-action').trigger( 'folderPick' );
```

To trigger the event globally so all subscribed elements get the event, do this:

```
$.event.trigger( 'folderPick' );
```

Comment: +1 for the `$.event.trigger()` i did not know it was possible, sexy

Comment: @meo I don't think it's officially documented in the jQuery docs. If there is, I haven't found it yet (or else I'd link to it in my answer) If you do some google searching for custom global jQuery events you'll find lots of articles explaining its usage, however. http://www.google.com/search?q=custom%20global%20jquery%20event

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm thinking of using $.event.trigger since I have icons with states I want to refresh depending on which folders are selected. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L317 may be of interest

Answer (score 2):

this is because you try to trigger the event on the document you need to do:

```
$('.folder-action').trigger( 'folderPick' );
```

and not:

```
$(document).trigger( 'folderPick' );
```

for example. When you bind the event, you bind it on a DOM element. When you want to call it again you need to select that same DOM element... Or trigger the event globally like in Dan Herberts example.

If you don't want this, simply make a function

Answer (score 1):

You are triggering the custom events on `document` but have bound an event listener for custom events to `.folder-action`.

DOM Events

1. go down the DOM (**capture phase**) until
2. they reach the target (**at target**) then
3. bubble up (**bubbling phase**) the DOM.

but jQuery custom events

1. trigger at the target (**at target**) then
2. bubble up (**bubbling phase**) the DOM.

So when the custom event is raised, it will be raised at `document` then bubble up, thereby never being raised on `.folder-action`, hence the `alert` is not firing.

You either need to bind your event listener for the custom event on `document` or trigger them on `.folder-action`. [An example of binding on `document`](http://jsfiddle.net/forloop/JAdv7/).